# Is it possible to use DataMember to overwrite serialized property value

Tags: c#, serialization, datamember

I've been playing around with serializing objects and I'm wondering whether you can use the `DataMember` attribute to overwrite the serialized value based on a condition? For instance if I had this property on my class:

```
[DataMember]
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

and I create an instance of my class where `Foo` is set to `IsFoo`, would it be possible for me to use the `DataMember` attribute to serialize it into something like this:

```
<Foo>Bar</Foo>
```

Note that this is a hypothetical question and that in real life this would surely be bad practice or a data-issue, but is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you cannot do that.

The `[DataMember]` attribute only tells the WCF `DataContractSerializer` to **include** that value (in the property) into the WCF message - it doesn't allow you to alter the value in the process....

If you need to have `Bar` in the WCF message, then you must set `Foo = "Bar";` in your code ...

Comment: I think you're right it probably won't make much sense to expect the DataMember attribute to act that way.

...and thanks for the editorial tips as well :-)